# Is this correct? Tensoring and long exact sequence of homotopy groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I would like to check that my reasoning is correct regarding long exact sequences. I have a fibration $p\colon E \to B$ with fiber $F$ and I wish to calculate rational homotopy groups. I claim that there is a long exact sequence
$$...\to \pi_n F \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_n E \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_n B \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_{n-1} F  \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_{n-1} E \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_{n-1} B \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to ...$$
which simply follows from the long exact sequence in homotopy and the right exactness of $- \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. Is this correct? I feel like there is a small detail I might need to be careful of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not only right exactness of $-\otimes \Bbb Q$, but exactness! This holds because $\Bbb Q$ is a flat $\Bbb Z$-module (or equivalently, a torsion-free abelian group).